# partial mediation with logistic regressions - total effect

Tags: logistic, effect-size, mediation

I am studying the effect of economic dissatisfaction on vote for the government at the individual level. I believe this relationship is partially mediated by attitudes towards the government record. The graph below presents the relationship I hypothesise, my IV is economic dissatisfaction (five points scale), my MV is approval of the government record (dichotomous) and my dependent variable is vote for the government (dichotomous).

[image]

Given that both the MV and the DV are binary measures, I calculate all three relationships/coefficients (a,b,c) with the use of logistic regressions.

**My question is: how do I calculate the total effect (the unmediated plus the mediated parts) of the IV on the DV from the logistic regression coefficients?**

---

I checked some of literature on mediated relationships and it seems to me that had this been a set of OLS regressions, one could use the following formula:

```
total effect of IV on DV = (a*b)+c
```

Is there a similar formula I could use based on the logit models?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it is c, if your logistics regression on DV and IV does not include MV.

Comment: $ab + c$ is the total effect on the log-odds, i.e. on your linear predictor. I see no problem in just reporting that. The effect of a unit increase in IV on logit$^{-1}(X\beta)$ will depend on where you start from because the logistic curve is non-linear.

Comment: and to get to marginal effects, I could then just use something like **_exp(β)/(exp(β)+1)_**?

Comment: This is now a question about interpreting logistic regression coefficients. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19764/marginal-effect-of-probit-and-logit-model) for a discussion of marginal effects in logistic regression.

Comment: thank you for your help! if you write it up as an answer i am happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula You listed $a\cdot b+c$ works only for linear structural equations. If we consider generalized regression model then the relations are given by $\mathrm{MV}=f(d + a\cdot \mathrm{IV})$ and $\mathrm{DV}=g(e + c \cdot \mathrm{IV}+b\cdot\mathrm{MV})$ where $f$ and $g$ are functions.

The total effect of setting $\mathrm{IV}$ from value $u$ to value $w$ on $\mathrm{DV}$ is then given by (Pearl, 2009, p. 132):

$E[\mathrm{DV}_{\mathrm{IV}=w}-\mathrm{DV}_{\mathrm{IV}=u}]$, where $\mathrm{DV}_{\mathrm{IV}=x}=g(e + c \cdot x+b\cdot f(d + a\cdot x))$.

With $f$ and $g$ specified by logistic regression equation the equation for total effect can't be simplified. I suggest You estimate the total effect through simulation.

Pearl, J. (2009). Causality. Cambridge university press.

Comment: but what is in this equation e and d? and how would you do the simulations? Seems to me that this just got overly complex... can't I just do what Will suggested?

Comment: @EndreBorbáth feel free to use the linear equations, you just need to be aware that the computed coefficient doesn't correspond to the total effect and can't be interpreted causally. $e$ and $d$ are the regression offset parameters and I assume you include these in your logistic regression model irrespective of the question how to compute the total effect. In the linear case $e$ and $d$ are included in the computation as well, they just don't appear in the final formula.

Comment: Suppose they are linear relation. Then DV=(e+bd) + (c+ba)IV. Why do not regress DV on IV directly to get the estimate of ab+c? I think this is kind of you create trouble for yourself when you drag MV into consideration.

Comment: I am sorry to insist on this and I really appreciate your help but can I ask you to point me to some link or literature by what you mean by regression offset parameters? I tried to google this but all the hits seems to be related to Poisson models. Can this be the constant in each model or am I completely off? Thanks again!

Comment: @EndreBorbáth yeah, what I mean is the constant, also called intercept. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @a_statistician Yes, the two approaches (one regression vs two regressions) should provide the same result, if the relation is linear and Your suggested approach is simpler and hence preferable.

Comment: i forgot to ask: is it the same formula if I want to know the confidence interval around the total effect? I just use the lower and upper bounds for the respective coefficients?

Comment: @EndreBorbáth I don't think that would work even in the linear case, since the estimate of lower and upper bounds may be correlated between $a$, $b$ and $c$ (even if the expected values are not). I would estimate the bounds through simulation, i.e. randomly generate values for $a$, $b$, $c$, fix $\mathrm{IV}$ to $w$ and $u$, randomly generate a large set of pairs $\mathrm{DV}_{\mathrm{IV}=w}$ and $\mathrm{DV}_{\mathrm{IV}=u}$, compute difference for each pair and the expectation across the set. Repeat for multiple values $a$, $b$ and $c$ to obtain set of values for tot. effect.