# How can I create a scatterplot in R using the plot function to control for covariates?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, scatterplot, conditioning

I would like to know if it is possible to create a scatterplot while controlling for covariates, such as in partial correlation. I am using R software and my code is below for the basic scatterplot.

I am not interested in multiple lines of best fit or multiple scatters per graph. I am also not interested in creating a lattice of scatterplots with all of the variables.

I can't seem to find any code that will allow me to parse the effect of the covariates from my x-y scatterplot. All three covariates are continuous. Any ideas would be helpful.

```
plot(pmc$reject, pmcp$LPA, main="r(Parenting, Left Amygdala)",
    xlab="Parenting Age 2", ylab="Amygdala Reactivity Age 15", pch=19)
abline(lm(pmc$reject ~ pmcp$LPA), col="red") # regression line (y~x)
```

Comment: One way would be to fit a regression model using all covariates, and then predict y values for x using some fixed value for all the covariates (either the mean, or the most common value for factors). This can be done with `predict()`.

Comment: Please consider adding a minimal example dataset for pmcp.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, one way would be to fit a regression model, and then plot predictions with some covariates hold at fixed values, and the one used on the x-axis with its observed values. The `R`package `effects` (on `CRAN`) can be useful.

Another idea, especially with three variables (but combined with the above ideas could be used with more) is *conditioning plots*, made in `R` with the function `coplot`. On this site some examples can be found [here, used for investigating interactions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44078/how-do-i-create-and-interpret-an-interaction-plot-in-ggplot2/44943#44943),  [another example with `R` dataset `swiss`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44078/how-do-i-create-and-interpret-an-interaction-plot-in-ggplot2/44943#44943),  and [used for investigating conditional correlations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203494/can-i-analyze-or-model-a-conditional-correlation/368228#368228), or [search this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coplot+).

Finally, one example, showing *conditional correlations*, from the post [Can I analyze or model a conditional correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203494/can-i-analyze-or-model-a-conditional-correlation/368228#368228)

[image: a conditional correlations coplot]